# Font Color Issue While Using in Mysql commands

Tags: php, mysql, html

I used the font color red, but in my page it showing green color.

```
<?php

include('connect-db.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {     
    echo '<font color=\"red\">';              
    echo $row['firstname']  ;
    echo '</font>';
    echo ':';
    echo $row['lastname'] ;
    echo '<br><br>';
} 

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this? Don't rely upon such HTML attributes. They have already been deprecated or about to be deprecated. Always use CSS.

Comment: You also don't need all those `echo`s, one for each line. You could use a `HEREDOC`, for instance.

Comment: If you don't need a separate CSS class right now then replace your `color` attribute in your `<font>` tag with a `style` attribute something like this `<font style='color:red'></font>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

include('connect-db.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {     
echo '<span style=\"color:red;\">';              
echo $row['firstname']  ;
echo '</span>';
echo ':';
echo $row['lastname'] ;
echo '<br><br>';
} 

?>
```